# Laravel - Recursion query for children and grandchildren (Refactor and making it fast)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, recursion

I have a recursive query which returns the `id` of children and their children and so on of a specific thread. I am storing the `id` during recursion as a string separated by an array so I can use `explode()` later on to get an array.

However, it is not efficient at all. The number of queries it will do is dependant on how deep the tree is. If the tree is very deep, it can take a long time to get all of the info, which is not efficient.

My table:

```
id | parent_id |
----------------
1  |         0 | 
2  |         1 |
3  |         1 |
4  |         3 |
```

Here's my code:

```
public function children()
{
    $all = '';
    $all .= $this->id;
    if ($this->hasSubforum()) {
        foreach ($this->subforums()->with('subforums')->get() as $subforum) {
            $all .= ',' . $subforum->children();
        }
    }
    return $all; //returns something like "2,8,10,22".

}
```

To call the method I simply do

```
$forum = Forum::first(); // One Query
$forum->children(); // Many queries
```

Is there a way of doing this without many queries? If the tree is deep it will do many queries.

Comment: Is this done in such a way so that you can keep track of, for instance, which comments were in a reply to another comment, or something of that nature?

Comment: No nothing of that sort unfortunately.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about the purpose and intent of this? It would seem as if the issue here is that you have many nested children relationships which causes heavy recursion depth. Sounds like the issue could be resolved by creating a `phantom table` that holds reference to all of these relationships, and are established upon model creation, in order to more effectively query the data.

Comment: The main purpose of this is to simply show all children of a given forum. I do this when a user can click on any of the children to see its associated info and its children.

Comment: If your table is a [nested set pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) then you can use [Baum](http://etrepat.com/baum/) library